File descriptors get corrupted when program runs in background
I have written a program for an embedded Linux system(petalinux). It runs fine when started from the terminal or TCF debugger.
However, I want it to run when the system starts, so I use the start-stop-daemon. This worked for some part, but now it completely stops.
What I see is that the program starts correctly, opens some files for GPIO and I2C access, and can correctly operate on them. Then, after about 8 seconds, these file descriptors are suddenly bad(Errno 9), and the software crashes or at least does not work anymore.
Further testing revealed that this also happens when starting the program in the background via a bash script:
#!/bin/bash
/home/user/myApp.elf &

Not putting it in the background works in this script. Also, starting the program directly from the terminal in the background works. I resorted to launching it directly via a /etc/profile.d script, which is more of a workaround as a solution.
I suspected some sort of memory overflow or corruption before, but executing the program directly always worked so far, while launching it in the background always failed, which does not smell like an obvious memory issue to me.
So, is there some Linux magic or weirdness happening to processes in the background where their file descriptors change or get modified? Is there some memory management thing going on I do not correctly handle? Is there some sys-call I do not correctly handle?
